# update metadata in s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I use Amazon boto v2.38 to write python script to access my S3 bucket.

I want to update a file in my bucket (I know it is called "**key**" in S3). The path is `MyBucket/myfile/demo.txt` . Besides, I want to also update its **metadata** named "`name`". Here is the code I tried:

```
# connect to key
conn = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = conn.get_bucket("MyBucket")

my_key = Key(bucket)
my_key.key = "myfile/demo.txt"

# if key exists, then update the file & its metadata
if my_key.exists():
   new_meta_data = {"name": "xyz"}
   # update metadata
   my_key.copy("MyBucket", my_key.name, new_meta_data, preserve_acl=True)
   # update file content in S3 by using the local file demo.txt
   my_key.set_contents_from_filename("demo.txt")
```

However, it doesn't work... I don't see metadata get updated. Why?

Answer (score 5):

You can just update the key's local metadata and then perform the file update:

```
import boto

conn = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = conn.get_bucket("MyBucket")
key = bucket.get_key('myfile/demo.txt')
key.set_metadata('name', 'xyz')
key.set_contents_from_filename('demo.txt')
```

Now `name` should appear as metadata within S3. Note, however, that the ACL might change when you do this.

It can also be done with `key.set_remote_metadata()`. This does not require that you update the key's content (but you can if you want):

```
conn = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = conn.get_bucket('MyBucket')
key = bucket.get_key('myfile/demo.txt')
key.set_remote_metadata({'name': 'xyz'}, {}, True)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. set_metadata sets the data on the object currently in memory (in python) and will only be applied to the object store if the object is pushed again.

set_remote_metadata sets the metadata directly on the object store without the need to push the object again, but it has a weird undocumented syntax (set_remote_meatadat(metadata_dict, {}, True)

Good blog post on the subject at: http://eddwardo.github.io/2015/07/01/boto-s3-and-remote-metadata/

Comment: Also note that set_remote_metadata sets the metadata exactly as provided in the dictionary and will delete previous keys/values. You cannot use it to update metadata, you need to set all the keys/values.

Answer (score 0):

The following code change the key metadata in `boto3`:

```
import boto3 as aws

s3 = aws.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Bucket('MyBucket').Object('objectKey')
obj.put(Metadata={'name':'newName'}
```

[According to the docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/migrations3.html#key-metadata), `set_metadata` must be used. I have tested it and the foloowing code works with `boto2` and changes the meatadata:

```
import boto as aws

cx=aws.connect_s3()
bucket=cx.get_bucket('MyBucket')
obj=bucket.get_key('objectKey')
obj.set_metadata('name', 'newName')
```

Comment: I tried `set_metadata('name','newName')` at the beginning of my project, it didn't work, then I changed to use `my_key.copy(...)` which is shown in my code.

Comment: could you try boto3? I have already tested the code I propose.

Comment: Our project is using boto2, this is the precondition of my question. But thank you for trying to help.

Comment: I have edited the solution, after testing the boto2 solution.

Comment: thanks, looks like the tricky part is the bucket.get_key(...) , which I didn't use in my code, I will try your solution tomorrow. thanks

Comment: This approach nullify original object's content when using `boto3`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Boto3, be careful if using "put_object" with metadata, this will change your actual metadatas, if you want to to create Object with metadatas, then add metadata or update an existing metadata, use the below :

```
import sys
import os 
import boto3
from boto3 import client

param_1= sys.argv[1] 
param_2= sys.argv[2] 
param_3= sys.argv[3]  
param_4= sys.argv[4]
param_5= sys.argv[5]

objectNMAE='THIEF.jpg'

s3ressource = client(
    service_name='s3', 
    endpoint_url= param_3,
    aws_access_key_id= param_1,
    aws_secret_access_key=param_2,
    use_ssl=True,
    )

def createmetdata(bucketname,objectname):
    s3ressource.upload_file(objectname, bucketname, objectname, ExtraArgs={"Metadata": {"metadata1":"ImageName","metadata2":"ImagePROPERTIES" ,"metadata3":"ImageCREATIONDATE"}})

def ADDmetadata(bucketname,objectname):
    s3_object = s3ressource.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=objectname)
    k = s3ressource.head_object(Bucket = bucketname, Key = objectname)
    m = k["Metadata"]
    m["new_metadata"] = "ImageNEWMETADATA"
    s3ressource.copy_object(Bucket = bucketname, Key = objectname, CopySource = bucketname + '/' + objectname, Metadata = m, MetadataDirective='REPLACE')

def CHANGEmetadata(bucketname,objectname):
    s3_object = s3ressource.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=objectname)
    k = s3ressource.head_object(Bucket = bucketname, Key = objectname)
    m = k["Metadata"]
    m.update({'metadata3':'ImageCREATIONDATEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE'})
    s3ressource.copy_object(Bucket = bucketname, Key = objectname, CopySource = bucketname + '/' + objectname, Metadata = m, MetadataDirective='REPLACE')

def readmetadata (bucketname,objectname):
    ALLDATAOFOBJECT = s3ressource.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=objectname)
    ALLDATAOFOBJECTMETADATA=ALLDATAOFOBJECT['Metadata']
    print ALLDATAOFOBJECTMETADATA

createmetdata(param_4,objectNMAE)
readmetadata(param_4,objectNMAE)
ADDmetadata(param_4,objectNMAE)
readmetadata(param_4,objectNMAE)
CHANGEmetadata(param_4,objectNMAE)
readmetadata(param_4,objectNMAE)
```